# Looking for an algebraic proof of an unusual equality

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have stumbled on the equality
$[\sum i]^2 = \sum i^3$
which holds when both sums are over the range 1 to *k*.  The equality is readily demonstrated inductively, but I wonder if anyone can provide an algebraic proof?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with *algebraic proof*.

Comment: The proof by Babak S to the question I inadvertently duplicated ("Proving the identity ...") is what I was looking for.  Thanks to all for helping me find it.